# Windows Phone App reviews not showing in Market Place

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone, marketplace

I have developed few windows phone app and published it in **Windows Phone Market Place**. My app got few reviews, I can see it in app profile but I can't see these reviews in Store. Can someone please tell How can I visible these reviews in **Market Place**?

Answer (score 4):

On the MarketPlace, you see only the reviews that were made in your country.  On the DevCenter, you can see the reviews worldwide. That's why you're not seeing the same number of reviews, it simply means nobody has commented on your application in your home country.

Comment: I have one more app. It has one review from my country. This review is also not displaying on market place.

Comment: @Ajay Then just wait for a while or contact Microsoft. In any case, you're not supposed to do anything to display reviews, all is done automatically.

Comment: Mine is same issue. Review is not displaying in apps page or in dev center. https://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/chillr/0dff7a2f-51f8-4de8-8e37-5e97fab540c0

Comment: @asitis, I can see your app reviews. Can you tell me what did you? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @SaqibRezwan I do nothing. It displayed automatically. But it may take 1 to 2 weeks to display reviews. very long delay!! :(

Comment: @asitis Thank you for your quick reply. It has been about 5 days since my app got some review and still they are not showing. So I became worried that, may be I need to turn some settings but could not find any. Now, after your reply, I am gonna wait for some time. Thanks a lot. :)
Can you just tell me one more thing, Can people from country A see the reviews from people of country B? I mean, can public reviews be seen worldwide?

Comment: @SaqibRezwan I don't think so since whatsapp reviews are seen based on country specific. But we can see the reviews by just changing the region in the link. eg. en-us , en-in etc...